# Apple Script : Cleaning textedit text

Tags: text, applescript, textedit

I want to clear some text from a textedit text but its only half working for me

```
tell application "TextEdit"

    set documentText to text of document 1
    set {oldTID, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, "Administration"}
    set textBits to text items of documentText
    set my text item delimiters to ""
    set text of document 1 to textBits as text
    set my text item delimiters to oldTID

    set documentText to text of document 1
    set {oldTID, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, "New Search"}
    set textBits to text items of documentText
    set my text item delimiters to ""
    set text of document 1 to textBits as text
    set my text item delimiters to oldTID

    set documentText to text of document 1
    set {oldTID, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, "Advanced"}
    set textBits to text items of documentText
    set my text item delimiters to ""
    set text of document 1 to textBits as text
    set my text item delimiters to oldTID


    set documentText to text of document 1
    set {oldTID, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, "Tips"}
    set textBits to text items of documentText
    set my text item delimiters to ""
    set text of document 1 to textBits as text
    set my text item delimiters to oldTID

end tell
```

For some reason "New Search" is still  on the text document.
Is that possible otherwise to only keep the text from the line 2 to 3 for example?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple text item delimiter calls can be tricky for AppleScript.  Try this:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to set documentText to text of document 1

tell application "TextEdit" to set text of document 1 to my RemoveThis(documentText, {"Administration", "New Search", "Advanced", "Tips"})

to RemoveThis(txt, termList)
    repeat with eachTerm in termList
        set {oldTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, (eachTerm as text)}
        set textBits to text items of txt
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTID
        set txt to (textBits as text)
    end repeat
    return txt
end RemoveThis
```

In this way, you can define a list of terms to be sifted through, and not worry about the coding details.

Comment: This works fine, also the world have to be in the same order in the script that in the text files. Thank you !